# what will happen if I change the value of int in Java

Tags: java, primitive

I have a very basic, silly question.

Let's say in a function foo(), I put:
`int a = 3;` // after this, I know it will allocate a space in stack and put 3 in it.

Then, I put `a = 5;` // Here is my question:

What happened after I put a = 5?

Will a new space is allocated and put 5 in it? Or it will find out the new space in stack and then put 5 in it?

Comment: The second one, if I understand you.  The "space" you allocated with `int a` is written once with 3, and then the same "space" is over-written with 5.

Comment: Be careful if you call the same function twice.  New "space" is allocated for *each function call.*

Comment: `javap -v` shows a single `int`. `iconst_3` then `istore_1`, and `iconst_5` then `istore_1`.

Comment: @markspace yes what I mean on "space" is bytes in memory.

Answer (score -1):

No it will not create new space just change value but if you pass this variable to a function will create new space as argument